# Standalone application to wrap HTML and JavaScript/CSS

Tags: java, swing, javafx-2, javafx, desktop-application

I need to design a desktop application in which user can fill in the data and generate an XML which can be saved on his machine, but the issue is that application should not use flash, PDF forms or should not ask for any kind of installation and if possible should work in windows/linux.

All in all I want to wrap a HTML page with some javascripts/CSS and present it to end user

I looked into JavaFX, which addressess all of my issues but the problem is it requires jre1.7(which most people usually don't have).Java Swing also can solve the problem but UI of swing applications are too naive.

I could do it in MSexcel/OpenOffice but my clients don't want that.

I'm open to all kind of platform/language.

Comment: Adobe AIR could be a good idea to wrap HTML and JS/CSS, because it was primarily intended for this. But it requires installation.
What about modifying the UI of Swing ? There are other ones included by default with Java. Have a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html
and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaFx with Java 6 if you include the runtime libraries for JavaFX (can be downloaded from Oracle [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/javafxjdk6-1728173.html).
If you ship the runtime with your application (just a bunch of jar files), your requirement of no extra installation should be fullfilled.

Maybe you can distribute your application with Java Web Start to make distribution even easier for your client.

Comment: I checked that but that will lead to significant increase in size of my application.

Comment: That's true. You did not specify a size limit to your problem, just told that javafx only runs with Java 7, so I wanted to correct that impression.
If you are using something like java web start, then you can cache required libraries on clients, thus the required download size for updates can be limited to the modified jar-files